# Access is denied error while publishing in Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, dd4t

We are getting error when publishing any page from tridion in Committing Deployment phase. We have a DD4T setup in which images get into the filesystem. Below is the cd_deployer log -

> E:\Web\Affinity\PCI\SDL\wwwroot\Website\Images\blue_callout_insurance101_125x125_tcm83-4888.png
>   (Access is denied), Exception occured while trying to commit
>   transaction tcm:0-70221-66560,
>   E:\Web\Affinity\PCI\SDL\wwwroot\Website\Images\blue_callout_insurance101_125x125_tcm83-4888.png
>   (Access is denied),
>   E:\Web\Affinity\PCI\SDL\wwwroot\Website\Images\blue_callout_insurance101_125x125_tcm83-4888.png
>   (Access is denied) for transaction: tcm:0-70221-66560 2015-04-30
>   09:21:45,585 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in Phase:
>   Deployment Commit Phase attempt: 2 for transaction: tcm:0-70221-66560
>   2015-04-30 09:21:45,585 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Retry is
>   supported for phase: Deployment Commit Phase in transaction:
>   tcm:0-70221-66560

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the deployer is trying to place your image on the filesystem as instructed but it does not have sufficient access to `E:\Web\Affinity\PCI\SDL\wwwroot\Website\Images\`.

Check what user your deployer website or service is running under and ensure that user has write access to the directory.

Comment: Its a issue with one image only, all other images in the component are getting replaced in the web folder except one where we get access denied. The deployer is able to update the images, not a deployer access issue it seems.

Comment: Then is there a file based lock on that specific image file? Perhaps from your web application or a virus scanner? It is clearly a file access issue of some kind.

Comment: Not sure how to check for the file based lock.

Comment: Google knows... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241178/command-line-tool-for-finding-out-who-is-locking-a-file

Comment: I am able to rename the image, does it still mean that it's locked. Anyway I can now publish the pages which were failing for few images. Now since I have renamed them, it's creating new images. Let me know how to overcome with this workaround.

Comment: Well, if you are now able to publish and unpublish pages with the image being managed successfully by the deployer then this definitely suggests an OS level access/permission issue to me. For the reasons behind that problem I think you will need to look somewhere other than Tridion.

Comment: Could it be bad/corrupt images?

Comment: No, as far as the Tridion deployer is concerned they are just binary files to be placed on the filesystem. It doesn't know (or care) if they are images or anything else.

Comment: Last call! Can it be like these few images were published by some other deployer earlier and now a new deployer it playing with them and its not allowing?

Comment: Well, that would probably depend on what settings and user/security level the other deployer was using. It's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This issue definitely seems like a file permission issue. I usually add modify permission to the deployer's incoming folder and at the web application folder.

Here's an alternative approach. Publish all binary files to the broker DB and use DD4T's binary distribution module to dynamically  retrieve the jpeg/png/etc...